# Saving Voice in Voicememo playlist in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, voice-recording

In my Application I am able to record audio.  It is stored inside Documents folder.  However I need to store my audio directly inside iPhone iPod or inside VoiceMemo so that the user can use with out loging in to my application.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not store or transfer the Voice Clips from your application to the actual Voice Memo application. Your application is Sandboxed and can not access the directory where the actual Voice Memos are stored or add to the list of Voice Memos in the Voice Memo Application

Comment: Thank you Suhail,  can I add as it to Photo gallery or to iPod lib.  some ware the user can view it explicitly like Photos and Vidos.

Comment: Hmm not too sure about that one. It is a voice clip so I don't think you can add it as a video which will then show up in the Camera Roll.